# why the output values length are getting reduced when using DB links in oracle and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, dblink

We are retrieving the output from table through DB link by executing a stored procedure and input parameters which worked previously and got the output in asp.net application.But now we noted that outputs through DB links are getting trimmed say if status is 'TRUE' ,we are getting as 'TRU' etc why the output values are getting trimmed.The only change we did recently was we changed one of the type of input parameter from `number` to `varchar` at the receiving remote side,But i don't think that is the issue??whe we execute the stored procedure remotely on the table.It is giving proper output but through DB link outputs are getting trimmed.ANy one has any idea about this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My oracle client is having issues,i reinstalled and it worked fine.Only my system was having issues.so i desided to reinstall